# Swift library that supports both app and extension

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I've created a library for my iOS app but I get the warning `linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions`.

I know this is because I haven't enabled `Allow app extension API only` for my library. So when I enable that setting my library gives errors where I have used `UIApplication.shared`.

I know I cannot use `shared` in my extension, and don't actually need to, but this library is used by both my app and my extension.

So the question is, how can I compile the library with a guard around `UIApplication.shared`?

I already use this:

```
#if !IS_EXTENSION
    // Cancel the background task
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
#endif
```

and set `IS_EXTENSION` for `Active Compilation Conditions` in my extension target, and also `IS_EXTENSION=1` for `Preprocessor Macros` in my app extension, however the library still gives me warnings on these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1st solution

I recommend you to use UIApplication injection into your lib. It can be achieved like this.

Your lib instance can look similar to this:

```
class DarrenLib {

    static var shared = DarrenLib()
    
    // User application instance everywhere where needed in your lib.
    private var application: UIApplication?
    
    func setup(_ app: UIApplication) {
        self.application = app
    }
}
```

As example injection can be done in the did finish launching function:

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
    
    DarrenLib.shared.setup(application)
    
    return true
}
```

I would not recommend use preprocessor macros, because it becomes depending on additional setup requirements which can not be done throw source code.

## 2nd solution

Also as you are currently using app and extension targets. You could create these frameworks:

1. **DJSwiftCommonHelpers**. In this framework will contain source code which will work on an app and extension target.
2. **DJSwiftAppHelpers**. This framework will contain source code which will contain UIKit specific cases like **UIApplication shared** instance.
3. **DJSwiftExtensionHelpers**. In this framework will contain source code specific only for extensions if here are any.

**DJApp** will be embedding *DJSwiftCommonHelpers* and *DJSwiftAppHelpers* frameworks.

**DJNotificationExtension** will be embedding *DJSwiftCommonHelpers*  and *DJSwiftExtensionHelpers* frameworks.

[image]

Comment: As well I am interested to see different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't like the idea of having to prep the lib. The lib is actually a bunch of helpers that i've used over the years and tend to import in all my projects. There's the odd one that isn't Extension friendly.

Comment: Do you have similar project hosted on GitHub that I would be able to experiment?

Comment: @Darren added 2nd solution, but it I could not achieve one framework solution.

Comment: Do you know 3rd party lib on GitHub which is working on app and extension targets and using UIApplication shared instance. If yes. You could look how they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers to your questions. In general, answer is both YES and NO.

First of all:

```swift
#if !IS_EXTENSION
    // Cancel the background task
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
#endif
```

This approach is more or less ok and would probably work, but for sure not with Carthage (that's what I see you use in https://github.com/ddaddy/DJSwiftHelpers), maybe with Pods or SwiftPM if you can assure flag is properly set on compile time.

The reason is simple and you actually answered it yourself - it is a compilation time flag.

Carthage compiles framework and builds the binary as a part of `carthage build/update` process, so you end up with already existing binary. This flag was already resolved, and was probably false, since not set. **So no build time flags in app or extension target would 'work' for carthage libraries.**

As for the carthage - what I can suggest is making additional targets/schemes in `DJSwiftHelpers.xcodeproj`. The same way as multiplatform support is handled for carthage libraries that have multi platform support, like both iOS, tvOS and macOS. Add a scheme `DJSwiftHelpers-extensions`, make sure it builds binary using proper build flags, and carthage will produce two distinctive binaries. Link one to extensions and second to applications, and it might work.

**Other possibilities:**

1. Use UIApplication injection as proposed in Ramis answer
2. Use the injection, but actually you can define second library to be only used for applicatyion targets, containing one ObjC class with overriden '+ load' method, like:

```objectivec
#import 'yours helpers library'

@implementation SomeClass

+ (void)load {
    // This is called once, when module is being loaded,
    // "Invoked whenever a class or category is added to the Objective-C
    // runtime; implement this method to perform class-specific behavior
    // upon loading."
    [YourHelperLibraryClass setupWithApplication:[UIApplication shared]];
}

@end
```

It is a bit messy, but will allow not to inect in app delegate. I would personally    not use it for that though.

3. Use cocoapods or SwiftPM - if I remember correctly, the library code would be compiled together with the app, so it's possible that it will "see" the compile time flags set there.